# Issue in generating .apk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, version

The previous version code of my .apk was 1 and version name is 1.0. Now i make some changes and now version code is 2 and version name is 1.1. but when i install on my device it says that "app was already expired, Please use another version. I don't know whats the problem. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: adb installation for developer or install from google player?

Comment: i am installing through adb.

Comment: change your versionCode not versionName

Comment: it still not works